# Based on the status need to populate the Icons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, mapping

[image: response]

Based on the status number I need to populate the approve and reject icon. In the response you can see the response numbers where ever status is 1 there I need to populate the ICons

```
this.state = {
 listapproval: {
            contracts: '',
        },
}
```

state variable listapproval has the following response shown in the image.
I am getting response

[image: This is the list and for this contracts based on the status 1 i need to populate approve and reject icons in the action column]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
   import * as TemplateAction from '../../actions/templateAction.jsx';
import TemplateStore from '../../store/templateStore.jsx';
import * as ClientAction from '../../actions/clientAction.jsx';
 import ClientStore from '../../store/clientStore.jsx';
import * as ContractAction from '../../actions/contractAction.jsx';
import ContractStore from '../../store/contractStore.jsx';
import * as UserAction from '../../actions/userAction.jsx';
import UserStore from '../../store/userStore.jsx';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';

export default class ClickableRenderer extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        cell: {
            row: this.props.value,
            col: this.props.colDef.headerName
        },
        text: '',
        openrejectDialog: false,
        openrejectedcomment: false,
        contractlist: {

        },
        singlecontract: {
            contract: {
                rejectionReason: ''
            }
        },

        rejectionsinglecontract: {
            contract: {
                rejectionReason: ''
            }
        },
        clientdetails: [],
        listapproval: {
            contracts: [],
        },
        userroleslist: {
            user: {
                role: {
                    permission: [],
                    name: '',
                },
            }
        },
    };

    this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    this.rejectClicked = this.rejectClicked.bind(this);
    this._templateStoreChange = this._templateStoreChange.bind(this);
    this._contractStoreChange = this._contractStoreChange.bind(this);
    this._clientStoreChange = this._clientStoreChange.bind(this);
    this._handleContractSelection = this._handleContractSelection.bind(this);
    this._getSingleContract = this._getSingleContract.bind(this);
    this._userStoreChange = this._userStoreChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}

componentWillMount() {
    TemplateStore.on('change', this._templateStoreChange);
    ContractStore.on('change', this._contractStoreChange);
    ClientStore.on('change', this._clientStoreChange);
    UserStore.on('change', this._userStoreChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    TemplateStore.removeListener('change', this._templateStoreChange);
    ContractStore.removeListener('change', this._contractStoreChange);
    ClientStore.removeListener('change', this._clientStoreChange);
    UserStore.removeListener('change', this._userStoreChange);
}

componentDidMount() {
    ContractAction._getContractList();
    UserAction._getUserRolesList();
    ContractAction._getListApprovals();
}

_templateStoreChange(type) {
    if (type == 'OrganizationList') {
        let organizationlist = TemplateStore._getOrganizionDetailsList() || {};
        this.setState({ organizationlist });
    }
    if (type == 'TemplateList') {
        let templatelist = TemplateStore._getTemplateDetailsList() || {};
        this.setState({ templatelist });
    }
}

_clientStoreChange(type) {
    if (type == 'ClientList') {
        let clientdetails = ClientStore._getClientDeatilsList() || {};
        this.setState({ clientdetails });
    }
}

_contractStoreChange(type) {
    if (type == 'ContractList') {
        let contractlist = ContractStore._getContractDetailsList() || {};
        this.setState({ contractlist });
    }

    if (type == 'SingleContract') {
        let singlecontract = ContractStore._getSingleContractDetails() || {};
        this.setState({ singlecontract });

    }

    if (type == 'ListApprovals') {
        let listapproval = ContractStore._getApprovalsList() || {};

        this.setState({ listapproval });
    }

    if (type == 'RejectionSingleContract') {
        let rejectionsinglecontract = ContractStore._rejectionsinglecontract() || {};
        this.setState({ rejectionsinglecontract });

    }



}
_userStoreChange(type) {
    if (type == 'UserList') {
        let userdetails = UserStore._getUserDetailsList() || {};
        this.setState({ userdetails });
    }
    if (type == 'RolesList') {
        let roleslist = UserStore._getRolesList() || {};
        this.setState({ roleslist });
    }

    if (type == 'UserRolesList') {
        let userroleslist = UserStore._getUserRolesList() || {};
        this.setState({ userroleslist });
    }
}

 _getSingleContract(id) {

    let data = {
        id: this.state.cell.row,
    };
    localStorage.setItem("contractIdforview", data.id);
    ContractAction._getSingleContract(data);

}

render() {
    let roleslist = this.state.userroleslist.user.role.permission || {};
    let userroleslistname = this.state.userroleslist.user.role.name;
    let listapproval = this.state.listapproval.contracts;
    console.log(listapproval);
    let statusaprve = listapproval && listapproval.map(statusnum => (statusnum.status)) || {};
    console.log(statusaprve);




    return (
        <div>

            {
                roleslist.map((roles) => {
                    if (roles.moduleName == "Contracts" && roles.permissionName == "Read") {
                        return (
                            <Link to="/previewContract" title="preview" className=" mr-2" onClick={this._getSingleContract}>
                                <i className="fa fa-eye"></i>
                            </Link>

                        )
                    }
                })
            }



            {statusaprve === 1  ?
                 <a className="mr-2" title="Approve" onClick={this.clicked}><i className="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
                 : null}



            {statusaprve === 1 ?
                 <a type='button' title="Reject" className="mr-2" onClick={this._openrejectDialog.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
                : null}









        </div>
    );
}
}
```

The statusaprve variable has the following statusas shown in the below image, and i am trying to populate the approve and reject icons based on the status 1 still the icons are not populating?

Comment: Why my question is unclear and not userfull? please anyone guide me

Comment: The code you have provided is incomplete.  There is likely an outer map/forEach/loop over some other data structure.  Lines 1 & 2 seem only relevant for debugging, the `this.state = ...` section seems irrelevant to the question, and the final 2 lines lack context for `this`.

Comment: I have edited the question based on the status i need to populate the icons.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this is still not clear.  The image showing the list of contracts can only be built if this.state.listapproval.contracts is an array, not a string as shown in your question.  So I suspect elsewhere you are looping over the array (for/forEach/map) to build that table, and there you can check if `status === 1` to determine if you need to output the Approve/Reject links.

Comment: {statusaprve === 1  ?
                     <a className="mr-2" title="Approve" ><i className="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
                     : null}

Comment: still i am unable to see approve icons

Comment: @DaveMeehan I have sent you the entire component code I think this will be clear. please go through

Comment: How have you sent it? - Sorry I see  you've amended the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell, as the ClickableRenderer class appears to be used for rendering each cell in the table (or some of them). `this.props.value` is copied to `this.state.cell.row`, and is probably an index into `this.state.listapproval.contracts`, but I'd think there are other props being passed, but the component doesn't document what props are expected.  You could `console.log(this.props)` at the start of `render()` to give a better idea, or look at the JSX where `ClickableRenderer` is instantiated to see what gets passed.

With what I can see, here is an alternative `render()` that might do what you want.

```
render() {
  let roleslist = this.state.userroleslist.user.role.permission || {};
  let userroleslistname = this.state.userroleslist.user.role.name;
  let contracts = this.state.listapproval.contracts;

  return (
    <div>
      {
        roleslist.map((roles) => {
          if (roles.moduleName == "Contracts" && roles.permissionName == "Read") {
            return (
              <Link to="/previewContract" title="preview" className=" mr-2" onClick={this._getSingleContract}>
                <i className="fa fa-eye"></i>
              </Link>
            )
          }
        );

        if (contracts[this.props.value].status === 1) {
          <a 
            className="mr-2" 
            title="Approve" 
            onClick={this._approveContract}
          >
            <i className="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
          </a>
          <a 
            type='button' 
            title="Reject" 
            className="mr-2" 
            onClick={this._openrejectDialog.bind(this)}
          >
            <i className="fa fa-ban"></i>
          </a>
        }
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

You don't seem to have a handler for `_approveContract` so you'll need to decide how to deal with that.

I feel for you, the code is pretty obscurely implemented.   You might want to consider adding `PropTypes` as this helps document and validate the passed props.

Much of what is put in `this.state` is seemingly unnecessary.  Read up on Stateless Components to see how this can be simplified.

Comment: this is not working this is my mailid can you check once in hangout. sivasai081@gmail.com

Comment: Happy to answer here or it doesn’t help the wider community.